# Openlayers zIndex for markers and vectors

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm rendering map with OSM and I have some serious problem with setting zIndex for page elements.

Part of JS looks like this:

```
var userRoute = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "KML", {
    sphericalMercator : true,
    styleMap: styleMap,
    rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true }
} );

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers", {
    sphericalMercator : true,
    rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true }
} );

markers.setZIndex( 500 );
userRoute.setZIndex( 200 );
```

Now while parsing KML file for first element I set

```
var startFlag = new OpenLayers.Icon( '/start_flag_2.png', new OpenLayers.Size( 23, 22 ) );
markers.addMarker( new OpenLayers.Marker( latlon, startFlag ) )
```

Same goes for last elem. :

```
var stopFlag = new OpenLayers.Icon( '/stop_flag_2.png', new OpenLayers.Size( 23, 22 ) );
markers.addMarker( new OpenLayers.Marker( latlon, stopFlag ) )
```

Setting zIndex is simply ignored by script, any idea why?

Comment: If anyone is intrested, you need to specify zIndex AFTER adding layers to map

    map.addLayers( [userRoute, markers] );
    markers.setZIndex( 1001 );
    userRoute.setZIndex( 1000 );

and it works just fine :)

Comment: Great that you found the solution. :-) Place it as an answer and mark it as solution for other to easily see that it's solved.

Comment: i just couldn't do it earlier cause i cant answer own questions for 8hrs ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If anyone is intrested, you need to specify zIndex AFTER adding layers to map

```
map.addLayers( [userRoute, markers] ); 
markers.setZIndex( 1001 ); 
userRoute.setZIndex( 1000 );
```

and it works just fine :)

Comment: As you have said "you need to specify zIndex AFTER adding layers to map" did the trick! Thank you!