# How to Click the Marker on OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I just make a map using openlayer

I made a map in OpenLayers with our own homemade

But what makes me confused is that I can not integrate jQuery with OpenLayers, where I create a function that is simple jQuery `show / hide ()`

I tried to click on one of the marker in OpenLayers map which I have made, which has id `#OL_Icon_43` inside `div#map` OpenLayers and I tried to do the function `hide()` using jquery in the `<head>` tag that will hide the  tag outside tag `#map`, but that does not work for me

Can you help me please ?

This is the view which I make the jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#OL_Icon_43").click(function() {
     $("footer").hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a chance that jQuery cannot find the element `#OL_Icon_43` when you are attempting to bind the click event. You will be better off [delegating a click event](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the `#map` instead.

```
$('#map').delegate('#OL_Icon_43', 'click', function() {
  $('#footer').hide();
});
```

---

**Edit**: It looks like OpenLayers allows you to bind events directly to your [markers](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html#marker-overlays).

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat);
marker.id = "1";
marker.events.register("click", marker, function() {
  $('footer').hide();
});
```

You just need to make sure jQuery has loaded before OpenLayers so you can hide the footer. I would recommend moving your javascript tags to the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much about your answer :)
But that code is still not working for me :( 
Can you have any idea ?

Comment: @user1532193 take a look at my edit. If that doesn't answer your question could you create an isolated example for me to look at?

Comment: Yeah, you are so great, this example code is 100% work for me, now i can use the function show and hide.

If i have any question agains about jquery and openlayers, i think i will ask a questions to you again :D

Thank you very much :) :)

Comment: I've been accept your answer, sorry if i'm late because this is my first time i use stackoverflow to publish my question and once again i'm so very grateful about your help :)

Comment: You have to make sure, that your marker layer is the top most layer to receive the click event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927162/openlayers-zindex-for-markers-and-vectors